# create a "mean rank" for a rank-frequency data.frame by R

Tags: r, dataframe

we use tidytext to generate a rank column for a data.frame.
as shown:
[image]

what we want to get is another "mean rank" column for the data.frame.
as shown:

[image]

are there any easy way to generate this column?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidytext)
dt <-data.frame(frequency=c(64,58,54,32,29,29,25,17,17,15,12,12,10))
dt %>% arrange(desc(frequency))%>% 
  mutate(rank = row_number())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sure, just group by frequency

```
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

dt <-data.frame(frequency=c(64,58,54,32,29,29,25,17,17,15,12,12,10))
dt %>% arrange(desc(frequency))%>% 
  mutate(rank = row_number()) %>%
  group_by(frequency) %>%
  mutate(mean_rank = mean(rank)) %>%
  ungroup()
#> # A tibble: 13 × 3
#>    frequency  rank mean_rank
#>        <dbl> <int>     <dbl>
#>  1        64     1       1  
#>  2        58     2       2  
#>  3        54     3       3  
#>  4        32     4       4  
#>  5        29     5       5.5
#>  6        29     6       5.5
#>  7        25     7       7  
#>  8        17     8       8.5
#>  9        17     9       8.5
#> 10        15    10      10  
#> 11        12    11      11.5
#> 12        12    12      11.5
#> 13        10    13      13
```

Comment: Come on folks, this is way too complicated, it may be that there are different interpretations of the term "rank", but there are actually built-in functions in R for this, see my answer.

Comment: true but I would argue that op likes to use tidyverse syntax. in my experience, the within syntax is rarely used  and hence less recognizable what is going on by others who check the code

Answer (score 0):

Use the built-in functions for this.

```
dt <- within(dt, {
  rank=order(-frequency)
  mean_rank=rank(-frequency)
})
dt
#    frequency mean_rank rank
# 1         64       1.0    1
# 2         58       2.0    2
# 3         54       3.0    3
# 4         32       4.0    4
# 5         29       5.5    5
# 6         29       5.5    6
# 7         25       7.0    7
# 8         17       8.5    8
# 9         17       8.5    9
# 10        15      10.0   10
# 11        12      11.5   11
# 12        12      11.5   12
# 13        10      13.0   13
```